# Build Vs2012 Sln through MSBuild comment prompt . with nuget reference

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuild-propertygroup

We are planning to build the solution through cmd using msbuild. The project solution (`.sln`) have the nuget reference. We are getting the error while building the project sln. like nuget error.

> Restoring NuGet packages...
>   To prevent NuGet from downloading packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages'.
>   C:\Program Files (x86).nuget\nuget.targets(89,9): error : Unable to find version '3.0.0.0' of package X'.

How to restore the nugets while building the solution?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet package restore is executed before the solution is built.

This error usually means that NuGet cannot find the package X from the current active package source.

can you check the active package sources from Tools -> Options -> Package Source to see if necessary package sources are selected.